# How were the ladies of the Mughal harem titled and styled?

Tags: ottoman-empire, women, mughals

The ladies of the contemporaneous **Ottoman harem** were, for most of its history, organised as follows:

- The sultan's mother, under the title of *Valide Sultan*, stood at the apex of the hierarchy.
- Next came the sultan's four favourite concubines, having the title *Kadın*.
- Next came those concubines whom the sultan had slept with at least once, having the title of *Ikbal*.
- At the bottom of the hierarchy were the other concubines and servant girls, having the title *Cariye*.

The most senior *kadın*, for example, would be styled, in full, as *Devletlu İsmetlu* [given name] *Başkadınefendi Hazretleri*, and might be addressed as *Başkadınefendi*.

**Is it possible to draw up a similar hierarchy and titulary for the ladies of the Mughal harem?**

Comment: Interesting. I think some difference arose from the Turkish vs Mughal culture with the Mughals having subsumed more Persian influences. I'll investigate my sources later if no one replies by then. By the way, I recommend the tag [tag:women] to categorize this further.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow through on your recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the book](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.131620) *Royal Mughal Ladies and Their Contributions* by Soma Mukherjee, "female officers of the harem were divided into three categories: the high (Mahin banu), the middle (Paristaran-i-hudur) and the low."

1. **Mahin banu**: "The internal harem administration was in charge of women officials called Matrons or **Daroghas**. These Daroghas were appointed by the emperor and it was a very honourable post. [...] Another important post in the harem was that of the [**Mahaldar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahaldar). They were selected from among the Daroghas. She was like a female majordomo and and even acted as a spy in the interest of the emperor.
2. **Paristaran-i-hudur**: "In the next grade of harem staff came the **supervisors** whose duty was to keep control over the maid servants and the dancing girls. It was their duty to keep a check on the harem expenditure and to give away the salaries and allowances to the harem inmates. [...] Another category of harem officials was that of the **Tahwildars**, who were in charge of the accounts of the harem. It was their duty to keep a check on the harem expenditure and to give away the salaries and allowances to the harem inmates.
3. **Low**: "The low category of harem staff consisted of the **slaves and servant girls**. They were usually known as *bandis*, and also as Khawas or Paristas. Their duty was to serve the emperor, the princes and important harem ladies."

I will also mention two other titles I've come across. The [Padash Begum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padshah_Begum) was something like a queen. I'm not sure if she was considered to have role within the harem, but if so, she would presumably fall under the Mahin banu. There were also female guards in the harem of Tartar and other foreign ethnicities, known as [urdubegis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdubegis). I assume this was a low position.

Comment: Upvoted, but—without looking at the sources—is this specific to a certain time period; when did this structure develop or was it like this from the creation of the Mughal state?